# Launcher not working, stops responding and resets the file explorer

Tags: command-line, launcher, 16.10

I am new to ubuntu and I installed 16.10. My launcher that searches application is not working. It stops responding and after a black screen i am back to desktop with every other application i was using closed and unsaved. On the other hand when i try to run a command in terminal. I am asked a password, when i try to right the password. nothing happens. Yeah i cannot write my damn password. Stuck here please help. THANK YOU.